# Differentiate Insert And Update

Tags: java, jsf, jdbc

I have a JSF page where I have input fields and values are being saved to database.

I would like to do insert and update. 
What is the best approach to differentiate insert and update, I wouldn't like to use flag.
I mean if flag is "I" then insert else flag is "U" then update.

Preferably like if ID is not null then call insert method else ID is null then call update method. ID is my primary key and it is auto generated.

I am using JSF 1.1 and database is Oracle 10g.

Comment: Why do need to differentiate in the first place? Do you not have different JSF pages for inserting and modifying data?

Comment: @Vineet Reynolds So same jsf page. Reason behind to differentiate is that I would know which method to call for, whether update or insert.Otherwise I need to use a flag which I would like to avoid.

Comment: but having different page for insert and update or two different options is more feasible and easy to operate. Is there any specific reason for not using flags?

Comment: What are you using to persist the data? This is an oneliner when using JPA as Java Persistence API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not typical to jsf but a standard design problem. I have seen this being handled in the following ways.

1. Get the id and call a select query. If the query returns any result, do an update else do an insert.
2. Update and then check for rows affected. If 0 then insert. Alternatively, insert and then check for primary key exception. Update if exception thrown.
3. Use an integrated update-or-insert if your database allows. This can be done in Oracle using the `merge` keyword.
4. Use a flag but that's ugly.
5. Always perform a logical delete and insert. This of course is a much bigger design decision and is implemented in applications that have very strict auditing requirements.

Comment: I would try the first option. Point # 3, you mean I create a procedure in database and then check for update or insert?

Answer (score 0):

```
you can do  like this....



<h:commandButton value="Update" action="#{bean.updateAction}"
                                                         rendered="#{bean.ID eq ''}"/>
      <h:commandButton value="Add" action="#{bean.saveAction}" 
                                                         rendered="#{bean.ID ne ''}">

    where id is an attribute in your backing bean initiated with empty string.
```

Comment: `<p:commandButton>` is from PrimeFaces isn't it? Also, the question is for JSF 1.1, whereas PrimeFaces requires JSF 2.0. Also, JSF 1.1 did not support ajax, so `ajax="false"` is useless, if I have to consider the standard tag libraries.

Comment: IF It supports Rendered attribute, Than it sufficient

Comment: Then edit your answer to use the tag library from JSF 1.1 Or explain the use the rendered attribute and how it can be used to solve the problem at hand. Your answer in its current form requires anybody to read your mind on what the code is attempting to do.

Comment: as polappan said id is primary key and associated with everyrecord. And Inorder to edit a record you should select it first. At the time of selection you have to populate id in backing bean. Anyway i have not worked with 1.1 jsf so, i am not clear about it. But i hve done similar task with jsf2.0

Comment: In my JSF page I have only Submit and Cancel button and hence I cannot use two buttons, one for Insert and one for Update.

Comment: Even with my suggestion also only button will be rendered at a time

Comment: @Vineet Reynolds, Sorry I am not familiar with jsf1.1

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't posted any code and neither is your description of your application anywhere near useful to me, I can only suggest using a hidden form field that contains the flag which is eventually is rendered using the [`h:inputHidden`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2_MR1/docs/tlddocs/h/inputHidden.html) tag. Of course, there is nothing to prevent anyone from changing the value of the flag from U to I when the postback happens. After all, this is JSF 1.1, and there is no concept of view scope.

You can however use the session-scope to store the value, instead of the hidden form field, but you must be clearing out the values when you no longer require them.